# Как проигнорировать точку в регулярном выражении?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно **10.2** записать одной строкой, а не розбивать на **"10"** и **"2"**

```js
var string = "10.2";
string = string.match(/\d+|[-+*/()]/g);

console.log(string);
```

Comment: у вас и так строка '10.2' вам её и регуляркой обрабатывать не нужно, держу в курсе. (опишите значения, которые должна матчить регулярка)

Comment: собственно то что регулярное выражение матчит я указал в примере кода, а исходная строка выглядит так: `5 / 7 - 4 * 12 - 5 + 15` "(", ")", "*", "/", "+", "-"

Comment: не вижу в строке '10.2' ... Вам что нужно то? На угад разве что `/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/`

Comment: @MedvedevDev Регулярное выражение вроде как это `/\d+|[-+*/()]/g`

Comment: Что она делает то, эта ваша регулярка? Опишите изначальную задачу которую должна была решить ваша регулярка, иначе вопрос не имеет смысла, так как это какой-то вакуум в вакууме.

Comment: @MedvedevDev мне нужно очистить строку от пробелов, розбить на числа и  символы + - и т.д и на выходе получить массив

Comment: Замените \d+ на `[0123456789.]+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const str = '5 / 7 - 4 * 12 - 5 + 15 * ( 2 / 10.2 )';
console.log(str.match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?|[-+/*()]/g));
```